# Azure Bicep issue creating a VM: "Subnet is not valid in virtual network"

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, subnet, azure-bicep

Any ideas why the following bicep that creates a windows VM is throwing this error. The NSG gets created but I cannot see the VN or the SN and the VM creation throws the error "Subnet 'sn-dwh-qa-02' is not valid in virtual network 'vn-eastus-qa-01'." I've removed some of the parameter definitions at the start.

```
param osVersion string = '2022-datacenter-azure-edition-core'

@description('Size of the virtual machine.')
param vmSize string = 'Standard_D2s_v3'

@description('Location for all resources.')
param location string = resourceGroup().location

@description('Name of the virtual machine.')
param vmName string

param os_storageAccountType string

param Disks array = []

param subnetName string = 'sn-dwh-qa-02' //TODO - Move to parameter call

param virtualNetworkName string = 'vn-eastus-qa-01' //TODO - Move to parameter call

@description('Provide virtual network resource group name to configure PrivateEndPoint')
param virtualNetworkResourceGroupName string

param storageBlobUri string = ''

@description('Tags to add to the resources')
param tags object = {}

@description('Commands to execute via VM extension')
param commandToExecute string = ''

@description('Private IP allocation method i.e. "Static" or "Dynamic"')
param privateIPAllocationMethod string = 'Dynamic'

@description('Private IP address of VM. This is required if privateIPAllocationMethod is "Dynamic"')
param privateIPAddresses array = []

param fileUris array = []

param networkSecurityGroupName string = 'vmdwhqa01-nsg' //TODO FIX

param addressPrefix string = '10.1.0.0/24' //TODO FIX

param subnetPrefix string = '255.255.255.0/24' //TODO - FIX '10.0.0.0/24'

var publicIpName = toLower('pip-${vmName}')

var nicName = toLower('nic-${vmName}')


resource pip 'Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses@2021-02-01' = if(!isPrivateIPOnly) {
  name: publicIpName
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: publicIpSku
  }
  properties: {
    publicIPAllocationMethod: publicIPAllocationMethod
    dnsSettings: {
      domainNameLabel: dnsLabelPrefix
    }
  }
}

resource securityGroup 'Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups@2021-02-01' = {
  name: networkSecurityGroupName
  location: location
  properties: {
    securityRules: [
      {
        name: 'default-allow-3389'
        properties: {
          priority: 1000
          access: 'Allow'
          direction: 'Inbound'
          destinationPortRange: '3389'
          protocol: 'Tcp'
          sourcePortRange: '*'
          sourceAddressPrefix: '*'
          destinationAddressPrefix: '*'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

resource vn 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks@2021-02-01' = {
  name: virtualNetworkName
  location: location
  properties: {
    addressSpace: {
      addressPrefixes: [
        addressPrefix
      ]
    }
    subnets: [
      {
        name: subnetName
        properties: {
          addressPrefix: subnetPrefix
          networkSecurityGroup: {
            id: securityGroup.id
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

var noOfPrivateIPAddresses = (length(privateIPAddresses) == 0) ? 1 : length(privateIPAddresses)

resource nic 'Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces@2021-02-01' = {
  name: nicName
  location: location
  properties: {
    ipConfigurations: [for i in range(0, noOfPrivateIPAddresses): {
        name: 'ipconfig${(i + 1)}'
        properties: {
          privateIPAllocationMethod: privateIPAllocationMethod
          privateIPAddress: (toLower(privateIPAllocationMethod) == 'static' ) ? privateIPAddresses[i] : null
          primary: (i == 0 ) ? true : false
          publicIPAddress: ((!isPrivateIPOnly) ? true : false) ? {
            id: pip.id
          } : null
          subnet: {
            name: subnetName
            id: vn.id
            //id: resourceId(virtualNetworkResourceGroupName, 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', virtualNetworkName, subnetName)
            //id: resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', virtualNetworkName, subnetName)
          }
        }
      }]
    
  }
}
```

I have tried messing with the subnet - I am not a network engineer I am an Azure developer that has had this dumped on them as nobody else knows anything about it. Could be a permission issue as when I go to the GUI after the script has run and create a VM in there the NSG exists but neither the VN or the SN are available in the drop-downs.

Comment: you address spaces for vnet and subnet do not look right. the subnet address space must in the range of the vnet. i imagine this template return some errors before creating the VM ? can you check if the vnet and subnet have been created ?

Comment: `I am an Azure developer that has had this dumped on them as nobody else knows anything about it` I dont think this part of your question is relevant ^^

Comment: The VN and SN scripts parts do not throw errors, only the nic script at the id line. The VN and SN are not created. I have no experience with subnet address spaces - the address space of 10.1.0.0/24 is the default, and the subnet prefix is what was spat out by an online calculator given the supplied address space as input. I suspect the address space could well be wrong and I am open to recommendations.

Comment: is your solution gonna run in isolation or are you gonna do vnet peering ? like vnet size just define how many ip can be assign inside the vnet. you prob need to goo gle that to understand what you need as vnet / subnet size

Comment: if your vnet address space is `10.1.0.0/24` you have 256 ip available from `10.1.0.0` to `10.1.0.255`. so your subnet can be same size `10.1.0.0/24` which mean you can only have one subnet. but it can smaller `10.1.0.0/25` (128ips), `10.1.0.0/26` (64ips) down to `10.1.0.0/32` (1ip).

Answer (score 0):

> "Subnet is not valid in virtual network" :

*The above error comes when the provided subnet address prefix is out of range from the virtual network address prefix.*

Thanks @Thomas for pointing in the right direction. If your vnet address prefix space is `10.1.0.0/ 24`, it consists of Ip's available from `10.1.0.0`to `10.1.0.255`. This means that you can only have one subnet because the subnet can be the same size, `10.1.0.0/24`. However, it can lower `10.1.0.0/25`, `10.1.0.0/26`, and `10.1.0.0/32`.

Make sure that your subnet address prefix is within the range of given virtual network address space.

And also, when you are trying to create subnets under virtual networks, use `Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets` resource to avoid conflicts.

*Below is the modified code and was able to deploy it successfully as shown.*

```bash
param osVersion string = '2022-datacenter-azure-edition-core'

@description('Size of the virtual machine.')
param vmSize string = 'Standard_D2s_v3'

@description('Location for all resources.')
param location string = resourceGroup().location

@description('Name of the virtual machine.')
param vmName string = 'newvmjah'


param Disks array = []

param subnetName string = 'sn-dwh-qa-02' //TODO - Move to parameter call

param virtualNetworkName string = 'vn-eastus-qa-01' //TODO - Move to parameter call

@description('Provide virtual network resource group name to configure PrivateEndPoint')
param virtualNetworkResourceGroupName string = 'xxxx'

param storageBlobUri string = ''
@description('Commands to execute via VM extension')
param commandToExecute string = ''

@description('Private IP allocation method i.e. "Static" or "Dynamic"')
param privateIPAllocationMethod string = 'Dynamic'

@description('Private IP address of VM. This is required if privateIPAllocationMethod is "Dynamic"')
param privateIPAddresses array = []

param fileUris array = []

param networkSecurityGroupName string = 'vmdwhqa01-nsg' //TODO FIX

param addressPrefix string = '10.1.0.0/24' //TODO FIX

param subnetPrefix string = '10.1.0.0/24' //TODO - FIX '10.0.0.0/24'

var publicIpName = toLower('pip-${vmName}')

var nicName = toLower('nic-${vmName}')


resource pip 'Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses@2021-02-01' = {
  name: publicIpName
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: 'Standard'
  }
  properties: {
    publicIPAllocationMethod: 'Static'
  }
}

resource securityGroup 'Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups@2021-02-01' = {
  name: networkSecurityGroupName
  location: location
  properties: {
    securityRules: [
      {
        name: 'default-allow-3389'
        properties: {
          priority: 1000
          access: 'Allow'
          direction: 'Inbound'
          destinationPortRange: '3389'
          protocol: 'Tcp'
          sourcePortRange: '*'
          sourceAddressPrefix: '*'
          destinationAddressPrefix: '*'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

resource vn 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks@2021-02-01' = {
  name: virtualNetworkName
  location: location
  properties: {
    addressSpace: {
      addressPrefixes: [
        addressPrefix
      ]
     }
     subnets: [
      {
        name: subnetName
        properties: {
          addressPrefix: subnetPrefix
          networkSecurityGroup: {
            id: securityGroup.id
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
resource subnetPbdResource 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets@2021-02-01' = {
  name: subnetName
  parent: vn
  properties: {
    addressPrefix: subnetPrefix
  }
}

var noOfPrivateIPAddresses = (length(privateIPAddresses) == 0) ? 1 : length(privateIPAddresses)

resource nic 'Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces@2021-02-01' = {
  name: nicName
  location: location
  properties: {
    ipConfigurations: [for i in range(0, noOfPrivateIPAddresses): {
        name: 'ipconfig${(i + 1)}'
        properties: {
          privateIPAllocationMethod: privateIPAllocationMethod
          privateIPAddress: (toLower(privateIPAllocationMethod) == 'static' ) ? privateIPAddresses[i] : null
          primary: (i == 0 ) ? true : false
          publicIPAddress: {
            id: pip.id
          }
          subnet: {
            name: subnetName
            id: resourceId(virtualNetworkResourceGroupName, 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', virtualNetworkName, subnetName)
          }
        }
      }]
    
  }
}
```

***Deployment succeeded:***

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jahnavi. That fixed the vnet and subnet issues - I had to comment out subnetPbdResource as it was throwing errors and wasn't referenced anywhere in the code. I added on the virtual machine creation code and I now have a functioning VM with NSG, VN and SN in place. I'd uptick the solution but it won't allow me - however this is fixed as.